# How to extract first letters of strings in python?

Tags: python, string, append, character

I did it this way. I'm sure there are many other ways to do it more professionally.
Don't mind my code, I started python 2 weeks ago and it's my first language.

```
"""Grab the first letters of the names:"""
names = 'Schmo', 'Nate', 'Wonderboy'
first_lett = []
first_lett.append(names[0][0])
first_lett.append(names[1][0])
first_lett.append(names[2][0])
print(first_lett)
```

Comment: If your code works as expected, and you're looking for advice about improving it, your question would probably be more on-topic on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to python! Nicely done. A more 'pythonic' way, using list comprehension, would be:

```
first_lett = [n[0] for n in names]
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome,
Another way to do this:

```
names = 'Schmo', 'Nate', 'Wonderboy'
first_letter = []
for i in names:
    first_letter.append(i[0])
    
print(first_letter)
```

Output:

```
['S', 'N', 'W']
```